# Installing npm on QNAP

Tags: node.js, npm, qnap

I am new to the QNAP, as I need to install crontab-UI on QNAP, but this Crontab-UI required or to be installed with the help of NPM (node package manager).

So is there any way to install npm on QNAP. If there is a way to install npm then its much easier to setup crontab-UI on QNAP

Kind Regards,
Anan

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manage crons of your NAS main OS maybe you have to consider installing packages through something like this:

> You can install a package manager called Entware on your NAS to
>   install extra tools and packages for Linux. Please note that this is a
>   free application developed by a third-party and as such is not
>   officially supported by QNAP.

**Source:** https://www.qnap.com/en-us/how-to/knowledge-base/article/how-to-install-a-linux-application-in-my-qnap-nas-that-is-not-available-in-app-center/

If you are just installing CRONs for your own purpose and you don't need to use the main OS you should consider using a **Docker Container** or **VM** with crontab-ui installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to edit scheduled tasks of your NAS you could take a look at "[WebCrontab](https://github.com/codeskyblue/webcron)" which also available on the [Qnapclub Store Repo](https://www.qnapclub.eu/fr/qpkg/231).

Answer (score 0):

As Francisco already mentioned: If you need more flexibility (and security - because inside the container neither you nor a future QNAP firmware update can break anything) I would install crontab in a mini Linux container.
On QNAP you can install docker - on QNAP the app or GUI is called "container station" and then search directly for a mini Linux or crontab image.
If you have Container Station installed you can also install containers via the CLI e.g. `docker pull okteto/crontab`.

The simple approach on the console of the NAS would be:

1] Edit /etc/config/crontab file and add your custom job. for    example: 12 0 * * /bin/syncmyqnap.sh

2] Test crontab    /etc/config/crontab
3] Restart crondaemon – crontab    /etc/config/crontab && /etc/init.d/crond.sh restart

Check QNAP's wiki for details: https://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Add_items_to_crontab